# A regex that doesn't accept 2 dot and 2 comma consecutively - Allows letters only

Tags: regex

- It only allows letters including ñ and Ñ
- doesn't allow other special character besides comma and dot
- doesn't allow 2 consecutively dot and comma in any part of the name

What should I add to my regex?

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A regex that doesnt accept 2 comma and 2 dot consecutively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695858/a-regex-that-doesnt-accept-2-comma-and-2-dot-consecutively)

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your regex as:

```
^(?!.*[.,]{2})[A-Za-zñÑ.,]+$
```

Explanation:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `(?!.*[.,]{2})` assert that no consecutive dots or commas occur
- `[A-Za-zñÑ.,]+` match a letter, including ñ and Ñ, dot or comma, one or more times
- `$` end of the string

Comment: I think single dot or comma should be allowed at first or in any part of name . Even in the ending part as long it's single not consecutive

Comment: .Suzaku. doesn't work on this example

Comment: I think it shouldn't allow  dot besides example and comma besides dot in any part of the character like this example : .,Suzaku or suza,.ku

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Can I ask how I add space here ? That will allow space in any part of the character ^(?!.*[.,]{2})[a-zA-ZñÑ.,]+$

Comment: I don't understand what you want here.  You should open a new question.

Comment: Already opened new question

Comment: I opened a new question @tim about email regex can you check if you have time thank you